# Problemas nas tasks do grunt para versionamento quando os arquivos html estão dentro de outras pastas

Tags: javascript, grunt, yeoman

Usando o Grunt, instalei e configurei os *plugins*: `- grunt-contrib-copy - grunt-contrib-clean - grunt-contrib-concat - grunt-contrib-uglify - grunt-contrib-cssmin - grunt-usemin - grunt-contrib-imagemin - grunt-rev`

Em minha arquitetura eu tenho uma `index.html` na raíz do public, uma `index.html` em uma pasta `firstapp` dentro da `public` e outra `index.html` dentro da pasta "secondapp" também dentro da `public`.

Minha pasta de imagens fica na raiz da public "`public/images`" meus arquivos CSS estão em `public/css`, e os arquivos `js` estão em `public/js/lib`.

Ao rodar as *tasks* do Grunt, a `index.html` que se encontra na raiz, onde aponta para os arquivos css com o caminho simples: "`css/---.css`", os arquivos `js` com os caminhos "`js/lib/---.js`" e uma imagem com o caminho "`images/---.jpg`". fica corretamente configurada, ele cria o arquivo "`raiz.bundle.min.css`" dentro da pasta `css`, versiona e o insere na página HTMLcorretamente, cria o arquivo "`raiz.bundle.min.js`" dentro da pasta `js`, versiona e também o insere na página HTML corretamente, comprime a imagem, versiona e insere corretamente em minha página HTML, perfeitamente como eu queria e como foi configurado.

Porém, ao rodar as *tasks* Grunt na `index.html` que se encontra em "`public/firstapp`", onde aponta para os arquivos CSS com o caminho "`../css/---.css`", os arquivos js "`../js/lib/---.js`" e uma imagem com o caminho: "`../images/---.jpg`", ao invez de criar a pasta css e js com os arquivos .bundle.min e versionados dentro da pasta "dist" configurada no grunt. Ele cria em um nível de pasta a cima, na raíz do "teste-versionamento", e sem o versionamento, apenas `.bundle.min`, e no resultado do `index.html`, a chamada para o arquivo fica "`../css/app.bundle.min.css`" e "`../js/app.bundle.min.js`", que não existem. A imagem ele comprimiu versiono e inclui no HTML corretamente.

E também, ao rodar as *tasks* Grunt na `index.html` que se encontra em "`public/secondapp`", onde aponta para os arquivos CSS com o caminho "`/css/---.css`", os arquivos js "`/js/lib/---.js`" e uma imagem com o caminho: "`/images/---.jpg`", ele cria a pasta `dist` corretamente, cria o arquivo "`app.bundle.min.css`", mas este arquivo `bundle`, vem vazio, e versiona este arquivo vazio, porém a chamada do arquivo no `index.html` continua "`/css/app.bundle.min.css`", sem o versionamento, e acaba que da `erro 404` pois não existe este arquivo. E mesmo se chamasse o versionado, ele estaria em branco. O mesmo ocorre para o `js` e para a `imagem`.

https://github.com/aldo-jr/teste-versionamento